# Creating a search box same as google using HTML and Java

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax

I am working on a functionality which says, whenever user types a text same employee name, the contents should be suggested in the text box same google does.

Eg. If the database has values for employeeName say "ravikiran" "ravikant" "ravikrishnan" etc, when the user types "ravi" in the textbox, it should suggest all 3 names and then user can select the option.

The data that is to be suggested should be queried to oracle database. I am using Java as a backend technology. I understand AJAX can be used to hit the Java code.

Can you suggest some good tutorials which I can follow in order to achieve the desired functionality!! I searched quite a lot but couldn't find something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Use Jquery autocomplete functionality  - 
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ 
upvote if helped

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is auto-completion. Rather than build it yourself from scratch, I'd suggest finding a Javascript library that can do it for you. For example, I have used [jQuery UI's Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) which works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the semantic-ui framework with autocomplete. What you need do achieve is, iiuc, exactly as in the example with [search autocomplete](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#/examples).